# Google Dialogflow: Get the id of Card

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm building a job search chatbot using Dialogflow. I want to ask user for the location, and return latest 10 jobs in that location. On clicking a job, I want to save that job id in context. How can I get the selected card id?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Google's location JSON object? You can find the docs here: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Location